# How to replace non-standard "for each" received from Visual C++ users

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, foreach

Visual Studio supports a pre-C++11 non-standard `for each` in their support for C++17 and earlier. I receive such code from users working with Visual Studio, and would like to replace it with standard C++:

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> v{};
  for each(auto i in v){ }
  return 0;
}
```

What would be a suitable replacement for the `for each`? I'm thinking it should be `for (auto i : v)`, `for (auto& i : v)`, or `for (const auto& i : v)`.

Comment: Do you know the actual, down to earth, difference between those three variants, themselves? If the precise difference between the three alternatives is clearly understood, only then can an intelligent choice be made as to which one is a more appropriate replacement for the non-standard syntax.

Comment: The answer is it depends what you want to do with `i`. `for (auto i : v)` means `i` is a copy of the value from the vector. The other 2 options `i` is a reference with the first allowing you to change the value in the vector and the latter not allowing you to change the value in the vector.

Comment: Isn't the "old" `auto` actually be `int`.

Comment: Or for example : `for each(auto i in v){ }` -> `for (const auto& i : v){ }` or `const auto`. Depends on whether you want to be able to change the oriignal value in the container.

Comment: You're asking me to know something about the non-standard `for each`. I didn't ask about `for each(auto& i in v)` (if such a thing can exist). Perhaps you are saying that the answer to my question is obviously `for (auto i : v)`?

Comment: Uh, yes. It's a thing in your code. You should probably get familiar with it before considering alternatives. I've personally never seen it before, so I don't have any ideas of what it's doing under the hood or what an equivalent would look like. Surely it's documented somewhere. Did you try searching for it? Or just burn it all to the ground and go with `std::ranges::for_each`.

Comment: It's an obscure vs2005 pre-C++0x feature. Documents are slightly hard to get (not in every region). Apparently that's exact  equivalent of  `for(int i : v)` with a different that it had probems with anything else.

Comment: why does it actually matter what the code looks before the refactor? Apply the same considerations as when refactoring `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) { auto i = *it;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc: [for each, in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=msvc-170)

> using a standard [Range-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/range-based-for-statement-cpp?view=msvc-170) for Statement (C++) is preferred,
> instead.
>
> When identifier is a Tracking Reference Operator, you can modify the
> element.

For native C++,   for each(auto i in v)
i is a copy of the vector element

```
for (auto i : v)
```